# Array assigned to variable is 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got multiple checkboxes to select variants.

And I am getting checked data from like this:

```
get violCategoriesFormArraySelectedIds(): string[] {
    return this.violCategories
      .filter((cat, catIdx) => this.violCategoriesFormArr.controls.some((control, controlIdx) => catIdx === controlIdx && control.value))
      .map(cat => cat.value);     
  }
```

then console.log output is:

```
console.log('arrViol: '+this.violCategoriesFormArraySelectedIds);
```

> arrViol: Unauthorized access to information, Getting confidential
>   information by supposedly trustworthy person (phishing)

then I am trying to assign it to my varaible like:

```
this.violation = this.violCategoriesFormArraySelectedIds;
```

but got error

> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

this is my variable. I tried also violation: string;

```
violation = '';
```

I tried also

```
this.violation = this.violCategoriesFormArraySelectedIds.toString();
```

and it "works" console.log is good but now..

I want assign `this.violation` to my interface (violation?: any; (I just tried any but nothing))

```
 answers: Answers = {

    id: undefined,
    name: '',
    date: '',
    time: '',
    violation: this.violation,
    description: '',
    numofpeople: 0,

  };
```

but `this.violation` despite the correct output in `console.log`
is

> undefined

when I am trying to do `console.log(this.answers.violation)`

I do not need put into my MySql an array output. I want just string separated by commas.

Comment: Can you please just show it all as one code block. I think you've got several issues, but it's hard to follow at the moment

Comment: A stackblitz would be good, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
this.violation = this.violCategoriesFormArraySelectedIds.join(', ')
```

This will convert an array of strings into a string with the elements of the array separated by commas.

Then you need to assign it to `this.answers`:

```
this.answers = {
    id: undefined,
    name: '',
    date: '',
    time: '',
    violation: this.violation,
    description: '',
    numofpeople: 0,
  };

console.log(this.answers)
```

Comment: it works like .toString() but this.violation is still undefined when i assing it into answers.
But is defined in console.log ... and output is good

Comment: You are not assigning it to `this.answers` in the code you show, only to `answers`.

Comment: it worked as I did violation as [] then
this.violation.push(this.violCategoriesFormArraySelectedIds.join(', '));